# generic 'data container' / namespace provider in .net

Tags: .net, ienumerable, iqueryable

Is there a generic interface that defines a nested "data provider" relationship ?
That is, some object, given an identifier, provides an object.

Like IEnumerable, this happens all the time and could/should/has been abstracted out.
It is already partially in IQueryable but IQueryable is very general, and does not always yields IQueryable itself, so it is not composable.

This happens in Rest service (website/rest datas), in the type system (class/properties), file system (directory/files), in programming (documentation/class name), etc, etc...

What would be the closest Interface representing this idea ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean... could you give a concrete example?

Comment: all those environment provides 'names', that is, from a root object and a name, you can retrieve an object. the filesystem is obvious, methink. Wpf does so too, with the particular behaviour for 'provided properties' that it will go up the chain to find the said object. but you can see the commonality between all those : root object + name -> (typed) object. likewise in an IDE, types are 'name providers' against which what comes after a dot is matched against.

Comment: so i wonder if the commonality between those have been abstracted out somewhere. for instance the bubbling up of WPF would be quite useful in the project I work on to control dependencies from outside.

Comment: hi @ThomasLevesque I found something which looks a bit like this in here : http://v2matveev.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/introducing-ustatic-check-unity.html, have to look how general that could be made.